# How would I use XMLReader to display an image?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document that I need to load and in the document it has several image sizes. But, I only need the medium image URL returned. How would I go about getting that?

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ipl status="">
<sizes>
    <image size="small">s/64654587.jpg</image>
    <image size="medium">m/64654587.jpg</image>
    <image size="large">l/64654587.jpg</image>
</sizes></ipl>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you saying, *"hey, can you write my code for me?"* I would recommend [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in this case, as it's easier to use than DOM.

Comment: I've tried, but I've never done anything like this before...I'm just a kid in school. I can only get the document name, don't know how to go from there.

Comment: Then you could: **(1)** Load the document into a SimpleXML object, then **(2)** Pull out the specific node you want. It's all in the linked SimpleXML documentation above. If you need more help than that, google *"php simplexml tutorial"*. If you simply can't make that work, come back and ask a question about the specific code you have that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SimpleXML things are easy:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$img = $xml->xpath('//image[@size="medium"]');

$medium = (string)$img[0];

echo $medium; // Output: m/64654587.jpg
```

If you need to read XML from the file use `simplexml_load_file` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php